# Find in files, Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find

Say I want to find all files that mention "Jonathan Appleseed" in a Linux system.

I see examples using grep, but I can't quite grep yet how to search (all directories from HERE).  So I want to look in everything below /var/, for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

haha. It will take hours :> in any case .... `grep -RE 'Jonathan Appleseed'`
R is for recursive, and E for case sensitive

Comment: No double-quotes required?

Comment: Yes, they are needed. I thought i included them (They may be deleted because i choose to present it as code. Anyway. Yes, they are needed

Comment: I had luck with `grep -RE "Jonathan Appleseed" .`

Comment: @bobobobo Yes, that will work for a simple `grep`.  Please be aware that using double quotes will cause the shell to expand variables before handing it off to `grep`. Single quotes will not do this *and* will allow the use of regex.

Comment: @bobobobo See also [this SF question](http://serverfault.com/questions/69283/when-to-use-single-quote-double-quote-in-grep).

Comment: I'd recommend including the `-I` and `-H` flag as well.  `-I` prevents binary files from matching.  Useful when recursing, because you never know what massive binary files might be out there.  `-H` includes the file name.

Comment: `-E` is not "for case sensitive". Searches using `grep` are case sensitive by default. The `-E` switch makes the search pattern an extended regular expression. The `-H` switch isn't usually necessary for a recursive search since it's on by default for searches involving multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

If your grep doesn't have the -R option,

```
find /var -type f -print | xargs egrep 'Jonathan Appleseed'
```

will generally do what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, the bar!  Thanks for using it.  What does `|` mean?

Comment: It is the "pipe". It *pipes* the output (stdout) of one thing to the input (stdin) of something else.  The pipe is just one part of [redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find all files that mention
>   "Jonathan Appleseed" in a Linux
>   system.

You're looking for:

```
grep -l -r "Jonathan Appleseed" /
```

If you want to run a command on all matching files, I would suggest:

```
grep -l -z -r "Jonathan Appleseed" / | xargs -0 <your command here>
```

Note that -l means show only the filename (not matching text), -r means recursive, and -z (if you choose to use it) means the file names are null ("\0") terminated rather than terminated with a carriage return.  This means xargs can handle filenames with spaces, tabs, and carriage returns in the name more readily.

I also am passing / to indicate that grep should start at the root of the filesystem ("all files... in a Linux system.")